# Magento2: Cross-sell not showing in cart, missing crosssell.phtml file

Tags: magento2, template, cross-sells

For some reason, my **theme** is missing the **crosssell.phtml** file that shows **cross-sell products** in the cart.

I found out from my Magento2 system.log file;

> [2017-03-26 21:21:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file:
>   'Magento_Catalog::product/list/crosssell.phtml' in module:
>   'Magento_Checkout' block's name: 'checkout.cart.crosssell' [] []

I tried to search in other templates for the crosssell.phtml file, but could not find it. Does anybody know what code I should put in the crosssell file to make it show the crosssell products in cart?

**I'm using Magento 2.1.5**

Comment: Hi remove checkout.cart.crossse this block from the checkout_cart_index.xml which is available in theme/any custom module. It will take the default Magento XML file.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

FYI, the file which creates the cross sell section is `module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply! Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to show the cross-sell items in the shopping cart (url checkout/cart/).

It used to work in Magento 1, all the items you mark as cross-sell for a product show up in the shopping cart. I believe it should also work in magento2 but it's not showing and I get the error in my exception log

Answer (score 0):

In the file `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`

you may verify you find a block definition like below:

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" after="-" ifconfig="checkout/cart/crosssell_enabled">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="crosssell.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
```

this tells you the default location in Magento installed version of your template is: `Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml`

However, if you look into this file, you will see it does get reused for related products, upsells and in general any products listing that have no toolbar navigation.

If you intend to implement your M1 template in this template, you have to bear this in mind.

The options you have that I can see may be to check how related products or upsells products have been integrated in your site. If you find something, then, it should make sense to reuse these for crossells.